# Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (Using Firebase)

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm having a problem storing data to my database through my html form, The error I get comes from my import statement which is: Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module!

Code below:

```
import {
  initializeApp
} from "firebase/app";
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "MY_API_KEY", //actual values are in my code, changed here for security purposes.

  authDomain: "My_auth_Domain",
  databaseURL: "FirebaseDb_URL",
  projectId: "Project_id",
  storageBucket: "storageBucket",
  messagingSenderId: "SenderId",
  appId: "appId"
};



const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


let inviteInfo = firebase.database().ref("inviteinfos");


document.getElementById("#regform", submitForm);

function submitForm(e) {
  let name = document.getElementsByName("fullname").value;
  let compName = document.getElementsByName("compName").value;
  let email = document.getElementsByName("email").value;
  let address = document.getElementsByName("address").value;
  let contact = document.getElementsByName("contact").value;
  console.log(name, compName, email, address, contact);

  saveContactInfo(name, compName, email, address, contact);
  document.getElementById("#regform").reset();
}
```

What I have tried so far:

1. changed import statement to the following

```
const {initializeApp} = require("firebase/app");
```

2. used import with firebase provided link

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.6/firebase-app.js";
```

3. used const with the firebase provided link:

```
const {initializeApp} = require("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.6/firebase-app.js");
```

4. Moved js from app.js into the main html page with a script tag of type module.
5. used `npm to install firebase` to retrieve the modules.
6. in regards to the link based solution I tried to remove the -app to see if it made a difference but it did not.

So far none of these have worked for me, the table I am trying to store information to currently does not exist but research has shown that running even without the table existing will create the table automatically for me.

Comment: *"Moved js from app.js into the main html page with a script tag of type module"* That should have worked, although there was no need to put the code in the HTML file, you just have to load the code as a module: `<script type="module" src="./app.js"></script>`. What did your attempt to do that look like? Maybe we can help you with whatever was wrong with it.

Comment: <script type="module" src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.6/firebase-app.js">
</script>
<script src="app.js"></script>

first i tried it this way, then where i have app.js i moved the app.js code into those script tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load `app.js` like this:

```html
<script type="module" src="./app.js"></script>
```

Inside `app.js`, you import `firebase-app` like this:

```js
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.6/firebase-app.js";
// ...
```

Here's an example (I can't use a separate file for `app.js`, but this demonstrates that it does work):

```html
<script type="module">
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.6/firebase-app.js";
// Check that it worked and returned a function:
console.log(typeof initializeApp); // "function"
</script>
```

You don't need a `script` tag for `firebase-app.js` at all, it'll get loaded by the browser because of your `import`.

Note that this will be using modules natively in the browser. All modern browsers directly support doing that, but obsolete ones like Internet Explorer don't, and separately loading modules like this can involve lots of small HTTP calls rather than a few larger ones, which can cause page load delays even with modern net protocols like SPDY. For that reason, people often use bundlers like Vite, Rollup, Webpack, etc. that combine modules into a small number of bundle files. If you like, you could look at doing that. But again, modern browsers natively support modules, so you don't have to.

---

Using `"https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.6/firebase-app.js"` in every place you want to import from firebase-app may be a bit of a pain. You have two options to make it easier:

1. In Chromium-based browsers ([only, sadly, for now](https://caniuse.com/import-maps)), you can use an [import map](https://github.com/WICG/import-maps):

```html
<script type="importmap">
{
    "imports": {
        "firebase-app": "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.6/firebase-app.js"
    }
}
</script>
```

That tells your browser that when you import from `"firebase/app"`, it should use `"https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.6/firebase-app.js"`.

Live Example:

```html
<script type="importmap">
{
    "imports": {
        "firebase/app": "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.6/firebase-app.js"
    }
}
</script>

<script type="module">
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
// Check that it worked and returned a function:
console.log(typeof initializeApp); // "function"
</script>
```

2. If you can't use import maps, you can write a module that re-exports everything from `firebase-app`, and then import from that module in your code rather than directly from `firebase-app`:

Your own local `firebase-app.js` file:

```js
// This re-exports all of its named exports (but not its default, if any)
export * from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.6/firebase-app.js";
/* firebase-app.js doesn't provide a default export. If it did, this is
   how you'd re-export it:
export { default } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.6/firebase-app.js";
*/
```

Then `app.js` would use `firebase-app.js`:

```js
import { initializeApp } from "./firebase-app.js";
```

(I can't do a live example of that with Stack Snippets, but [here's that on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/re-exporting-example-wth9b5).)

Comment: So i tried this, as you said

the error i get now is this: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "firebase/app". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

on my form page my script tag looks like this 

`<script type= "module" src="./app.js"></script>`

and my import statement on app.js is this:
  `import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.6/firebase-app.js";`

Comment: @AbbasHusain - Find wherever it is in your code that's importing from `firebase/app` and update it to use the module specifier in the answer above. If you do that, it does work.

Comment: I copied and pasted it into my code @T.J. Crowder,

Comment: It worked, I do not get the error anymore, the reason it was there now was because i had not cleared the browser cache, sorry about that.